# О грамматике и правописании

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Четыре строки из стихотворения «Мороз» (Д. Самойлов. Сборник «Залив». М., 1981) самим автором были признаны неудачей. Говорилось, что допущенный изъян в грамматическом строе обернулся преломлением поэтической мысли. О каких (вообще или ещё) несовершенствах этого четверостишия могла идти речь?

> Повторов нет! Неповторимы
>
> Ни мы, ни ты, ни я, ни он.
>
> Неповторимы эти зимы
>
> И этот лёгкий ковкий звон...

Comment: В упор не вижу грамматических изъянов. Если к чему и мог бы я придраться, то лишь к строке "неповторимы эти зимы": здесь использовано множественное число, и выходит, что неповторим некий кластер зим минимум из двух штук. А внутри кластера зимы могут повторяться. Но это уж если совсем придираться.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже не вижу изъянов в грамматике, Может, **согласование по числу** Самойлову не нравится, но он просто Розенталя не читал.  Не знаю, куда там "преломилась мысль", лучше уже куда-нибудь преломилась, интересней было бы...

А стихотворение так себе, **скучное.** Много красивостей, да и мысль эта не нова, к тому же изложена прямым текстом.

**Современная поэзия должна быть другой** – иносказательной, неожиданной, в чем-то парадоксальной и в то же время яркой, конкретной, вещественной. А здесь поэт топчется в одном измерении, одну картинку всё никак не нарисует...

К мысли читателя надо подвести, а не делать выводы за него. И розы эти надоели, и мгновение, которое надо ловить.

В общем, никакого эстетического удовольствия. Но критики его разбирают, объясняют...

Лучше уж **Тютчева** почитать (о вечной красоте того, что кажется преходящим)

..*.Не все, что здесь цвело, увянет,*

*Не все, что было здесь, пройдет!*

.*..И увядание земное*

*Цветов не тронет неземных,*

*И от полуденного зноя*

*Роса не высохнет на них.*